# How to use MySQL, InnoDB Spatial indexes in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, spatial, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use spatial columns in a Rails app to query the DB for points within a bounding box.

I have heard that MySQL 5.7+ can do that fine with InnoDB, but I don't know how to set it up.

I tried using https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-mysql2spatial-adapter but couldn't create the db, then realised it's not very actively maintained.

Has anyone done this recently/know how to configure a DB to have a model with a spatial column that can be used for a bounding box query?

Comment: Ever come up with any information on this? I'd love it if you had an answer.

Comment: No, I ended up storing lat and lng in separate decimal columns, and using `geokit-rails` gem for it's `in_bounds` method. It's not what I wanted, but it gets the job done well enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking at https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder and it looks good, but no spatial indices.